# Preview select freehand pen tool

Tags: preview, big-sur

Since a recent preview update there is no freehand pen tool in the markup toolbar anymore

[image]

There is only the shapes/arrows/best-guess pen tool.

I can force it to be freehand by two clicks after drawing every single line:

[image]

Preview used to be my go-to for drawing diagrams or annotating screenshots quickly.

Is there a way to select freehand drawing tool by default in Preview? Or reveal it in toolbar? Or not require me to click after drawing every line?

Or, what is now the most painless and fastest way to freehand draw in macOS?

Comment: Isn't this the same as  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/402396/freehand-preview-pen-missing